# htaccess prevent access to files EXCEPT from a specific path

Tags: .htaccess, file, permissions

I'm preventing user access to my image uploads directory like this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?localhost/ [NC] 
RewriteRule \.(jpe?g|gif|bmp|png)$ - [F,NC]
```

However, I'd like to be able to access them myself when I'm managing them - all of this happens within the /admin path. How can I add that exception?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use another `RewriteCond`:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?localhost/ [NC] 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/admin/ [NC]
RewriteRule \.(jpe?g|gif|bmp|png)$ - [F,NC]
```

Comment: Just a follow-up question: What if I wanted to do this, but besides only allowing direct access through /admin/, I wanted to block just a specific path, like /uploads/textures/[image files] ?

Comment: Then you can just use: `RewriteRule ^uploads/textures/.+?\.(jpe?g|gif|bmp|png)$ - [F,NC]`